# How to use DFT to solve this minimization problem?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, fa.functional-analysis

This is a problem when I'm reading a paper.

Equation:

$min\{\sum_p(S_p-I_p)^2+\beta((\partial_xS_p-h_p)^2+(\partial_yS_p-v_p)^2) \} $

where  $S,I,h,v$ are all $M*N$ matrices and p stands for every element in the Matrix. $I,h,v$ are known.

The paper just mentioned "we diagonalize derivative operators after Fast Fourier Transform for speedup" and get the solution

$S=\mathscr{F}^{-1}\left(\frac{\mathscr{F}(I)+\beta(\mathscr{F}(\partial_x)^*\mathscr{F}(h)+\mathscr{F}(\partial_y)^*\mathscr{F}(v))}{\mathscr{F}(1)+\beta(\mathscr{F}(\partial_x)^*\mathscr{F}(\partial_x)+\mathscr{F}(\partial_y)^*\mathscr{F}(\partial_y)}\right)$

where $\mathscr{F}(1)$ stands for FFT of delta function. Plus, multiplication and division are all component-wise.  "*" means conjugation.

I've looked up some books but still can't get how this happen. I don't find any connection between DFT and minimization or quadratic function.

Here's the [paper](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~leojia/papers/L0smooth_Siggraph_Asia2011.pdf), equation is on page 4.

Comment: siggraph papers are notoriously hard to reproduce. It will be very hard to get results as good as you see in that publication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to minimize the objective function

$$f:S \mapsto \| S-I\|_2^2+\beta(\| \partial_xS-h\|^2_2+\|\partial_yS-v\|_2^2) $$

where $\| \cdot \|_2$ is the "entrywise" $\ell^2$ norm. This is done as usual: the global minimum $S$ must be a critical point and then the derivative must be zero at $S$. The differential of the objective function is given by

$$Df(S)(M) = 2\langle S-I,M\rangle  +  \beta\left( 2 \langle\partial_x S -h,\partial_x M\rangle + 2 \langle\partial_y S - v,\partial_y M \rangle \right)$$

where  $\langle A,B \rangle = \sum_p A_p B_p$  (the "entrywise" inner product). Now, that for any $M$ the last expression vanishes implies that

$$ S-I + \beta( \partial_x^T \partial_x S-\partial_x^Th + \partial_y^T \partial_y S -\partial_y^Tv) =0.$$

($\cdot^T$ is the adjoint operator). Now you can take the DFT on both sides,

$$ \mathscr{F}(S) - \mathscr{F}(I) + \beta \left( \mathscr{F}(\partial_x^T\partial_x S) - \mathscr{F}(\partial_x^Th)+ \mathscr{F}(\partial_y^T\partial_y S) - \mathscr{F} (\partial_y^Tv)\right)=0,$$
and then use the fact that the DFT diagonalizes the gradient $\mathscr{F}(\partial_. S) = \mathscr{F}(\partial_\cdot ) \mathscr{F} (S)$ and some algebra to find that
$$ (\mathscr{F}(1) + \beta (\mathscr{F}(\partial_x)^*\mathscr{F}(\partial_x) + \mathscr{F}(\partial_y)^*\mathscr{F}(\partial_y) ))\mathscr{F}(S)= \mathscr{F}(I) + \beta \left(  \mathscr{F}(\partial_x)^*\mathscr{F}(h) + \mathscr{F}(\partial_x)^*\mathscr{F} (v)\right)$$
and solving for $S$ this gives the formula asked. (Remark: We could have written the objective function directly in terms of $\mathscr{F}(S)$ using Parseval and then optimize).

As for the speedup part, we would have to invert a very large ($NM \times NM$) matrix representing the operator 
$$ 1 + \beta( \partial_x^T \partial_x + \partial_y^T \partial_y )$$
if we do it directly in image space.

Comment: Thanks! I think that's what I'm looking for! But what does "the fact that the DFT diagonalizes the gradient" mean? I've read it somewhere but don't get it. Anywhere I can find some detail?

Comment: @Co "DFT diagonalizes the gradient" - means Fourier transform of d/dx is diagonal operator - this means that if you consider F * d/dx  * F^{-1}  - this will be diagonal matrix. Formula F * d/dx * F^{-1} is usually  abbreviated as F(d/dx). (For mathematician such an abbreviation is natural - induced action of operators on matrices).

Comment: @Alex Thank you! F is the DFT Matrix right? Can you give me some books or something I can find some proof of it?

Comment: @Co Yes. F - stands for DFT matrix. The fact that  x F f(t) = F d/t f(t)  which is the same as x =F^{-1} d/dt F is simple basic fact which is described in any textbook on Fourier analysis. In discrete version it is related to the fact that F^{-1} DiagMatr F = Circulant. I am sorry I have not any text book at hand to point out the pages. But I think looking on Wikipedia you can find it relevant textbooks.

Comment: @Alex I learned DFT from <Digital Image Processing> by Gonzalez, seems it omits some important theories. I will refer to some other book. Anyway, thank you:-)

Comment: How to get the differential of the objective function? Why it's Df(S)(M)=2⟨S−I,M⟩+β(2⟨∂xS−h,∂xM⟩+2⟨∂yS−v,∂yM⟩)?

Comment: You can get using the "Gateau" definition of derivative. Namely, if you have a function J, you can get it's Gateau derivative in point S, using the formula: lim (epsilon ->0) 1/epsilon * [J(S + epsilon * M) - J(S)]

Answer (score 0):

FFT is used only to "speed-up".
If no need to speed-up this formula looks like standard minimal least square answer.

Which works like this - assume you need to minimize in x :  |Mx-v|^2   for some rectangular matrix M. The answer is well-known x= inverse(M*M^t)*M V. Remark: The matrix  M * inverse(M*M^t)  is called Moore-Penrose pseaudoinverse.

Now what is M in yours example ?

M = 1 + d/dx + d/y

So M*M^t  - will be what stands in denominator, while Mv - this what stands in numerator.

If you want to speed-up - put "F" everywhere.

I am not sure my answer is clear. Please comment if you need more details.

Comment: I, for one, do not understand this answer. What do you mean "put F everywhere"? And why does that speed anything up?


Comment: why M=1+dx+dy? M-P inverse is only used in ||Mx-v|| (||x+dx x + dy x -v||) right? So how can M be 1+dx+dy in this example? 
And how to use FFT to speed up anything in M-P inverse?
The paper says the trivial way to solve this equation is to use gradient decent, which is very very slow, so they come with a way to speed it up.

Comment: @Igor,Co Assume you need calculate C*v  - just put F: F^{-1} * (F C F^{-1}) * F v . Why it speeds - calculation C*v takes n^2 operations. Assume FCF^{-1} is known to you - like in this example because C and it is diagonal  like in this example since C= d/dx  , under this assumption you need n-operations to calculate   Diag * Cv . And nlogn to make FFT. So instead of original n^2 you get n log n. Is it clear ? Sorry need to run home.

Comment: @Co why M=1+dx+dy?  Good question I am also not very clear but I guess it is due to fact that dx and dy actss on different variables - I think I can clarify it, but may be tomorrow...

Comment: Hi @AlexanderChervov! I'm working on a problem similar to this, except that my h=v=0 but, the derivative of my matrix S is multiplied point-wise with a weight matrix W_x and W_y. I can follow the same procedure to solve the optimization problem, but when I apply FFT, I got F*(dx)F(W_x `o` dx(S)) where `o` is point wise multiplication. How can I isolate S to have a closed form formula for S? in other words, what is the DFT of point wise multiplication? thank you in advance!